# distinct - mysql result

Tags: mysql, sql

I hava a problem with distinct In every row by id I have 100 results. 
I must show results for hearrate for player_id = 1, but it's only show about 250 results. It must be about 400

```
SELECT city.player_id, city.team_id, country.gender, account.first_name, 
account.last_name, 
city.position,player.status,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(playing))
FROM account
JOIN player
ON account.id = player.account_id JOIN city
ON player.id = city.player_id JOIN player_activity
ON player.id = player_activity.player_id JOIN team
ON city.team_id = country.id
GROUP BY player.id;
```

Any idea why is this doing?

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 0):

You are only grouping by 1 of the columns that is not being aggregated., MySQL lets you do this but it produces inconsistent results

Try:

```
select city.player_id, city.team_id, country.gender, account.first_name, 
account.last_name, 
city.position,player.status,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(playing))
FROM account
JOIN player
ON account.id = player.account_id JOIN city
ON player.id = city.player_id JOIN player_activity
ON player.id = player_activity.player_id JOIN team
ON city.team_id = country.id
GROUP BY city.player_id, city.team_id, country.gender, account.first_name, 
account.last_name, 
city.position,player.status
```

;

Answer (score 0):

Logically, the information you are asking the SQL to give you doesn't make any sense.  Your query is asking SQL to return an individual record per player.id, yet you are also specifying that you would like to see several other columns displayed with this information.

How would you expect SQL to display to you a list of rows for (teamId, gender, etc..) that all have multiple rows in the database, when each of their player.id's was lumped into a single result (row)?

In essence, the query you are attempting to execute is invalid for this reason, and SQL is behaving weird/throwing errors because of this.  Assuming that you can't aggregate fields like teamId and gender, I think you are a bit confused on what you are wanting SQL to do for you. What you really are wanting is SQL to ORDER BY, not GROUP BY, because you would like to see your results categorized by player.id rather than lumped into it.  If you change your "GROUP BY" to an "ORDER BY", I'm betting you will see the results you are asking for.  Hope this helps.